# MD5 for Git's git-credential-osxkeychain executable?

Tags: security, git, github, checksum, md5

*This question copied over from Super-User, where it was apparently unwelcome. Anyway, asked and answered:*

I'm setting up a GitHub account and have downloaded Git's `git-credential-osxkeychain` executable via the Password Caching section of [GitHub's instructions](https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git#password-caching). But... I am paranoid enough to look for some reassurance that I've got my hands on the right thing. Can anybody out there verify an MD5 for the executable at http://github-media-downloads.s3.amazonaws.com/osx/git-credential-osxkeychain? ***(Yes, that is a direct link to the exe!)***  Better yet, point to an official source.

Comment: Just because something is off-topic on super user isn't a reason to post it here.  Questions on serverfault should be directly related to system administration in some way.  I don't see how this question is.  Your question is also too localized and will be worthless to almost anyone else in the future since it doesn't appear to have any version information.  What happens when `git-credential-osxkeychain` is updated?  Questions here are expected to be generally useful, and not be limited to a very specific set of circumstances.

Comment: As for verifying the security of something MD5 sucks.  You would be far better off looking for an SHA512, or a GPG signature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nice folks at GitHub inform me that

> The MD5 checksum is `dc84cd7df3a91af7e41f9a00b30bde78`.

which is what I get.